# Android IMU from uncalibrated to calibrated algorithm

Tags: android, android-sensors, calibration, imu

I was wondering, how does android makes its calibration on IMU sensors (Acc_calibrated, Gyro_calibrated), I know that there is an intrinsic calibration for temperature that happens in calibrated and uncalibrated versions (its chip based), but I want to know the android algo for calibration. (Maybe its even vendor specific?)

Tried looking for it in android source code (sensor.h, sensor.cpp, fusion.cpp and stuff), couldnt find it

UPDATE: seems like it is chip vendor specific